# Hide main div if wp_nav_menu is empty

Tags: php, functions, menus

I want to hide the div class "navmain2" if the menu is empty. See code below:

```
<!-- Start main navigation -->

<div class="navmain2">
    <div id="logo"></div>

    <!-- Gets main menu by id -->
    <span></span>
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu' => 11,
            'container' =>false,
            'menu_class' => 'nav',
            'echo' => true,
            'before' => '',
            'after' => '',
            'link_before' => '',
            'link_after' => '',
            'depth' => 0,
            'walker' => new description_walker())
        );
    ?>
    <!-- /main menu -->

    <div id="klicka">Click here! Click here! Click here</div>
</div><!-- /main navigation -->-->
```

I have a logo and a div with text inside **navmain2** as you can see.

*The question is:*

**Is it possible to hide the whole navmain2 div if the wp_nav_menu is empty?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assign the menu to a string:

```
$menu = wp_nav_menu(
    array (
        'echo' => FALSE,
        'fallback_cb' => '__return_false'
    )
);

if ( ! empty ( $menu ) )
{
    echo '<div class="navmain2">' . $menu . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: So should i edit the code or this is a seperate function that ill add in the same page ?

Comment: @MeiasSafa Use it instead of your code at the same place.

Comment: Cant get it to work. Because i have 2 divs in the main page. one called navmain and the other navmain2 and i just wanna hide navmain2 if it is empty.

Answer (score 6):

If you wanted to check there is a menu assigned you could use [has_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_nav_menu). Passing through the registered menu id as registered via [register_nav_menu()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu)

```
 <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) { ?>

    <div class="navmain2">

    </div>

 <?php }
```

Note: This function will output the div if the location `primary` has a menu assigned, it will also output the div if the menu is assigned and empty

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it's much more clearer then the current. I would just use the other format for the `if` block: `if () : ?> <?php endif;` when mixing with HTML.

Comment: Confirmed working in WordPress v4.9 for people still running old builds.

Answer (score 1):

Determines whether a registered nav menu location has a menu assigned to it. [know more](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_nav_menu/)

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution nr 2:**

Is to hide the div thru Js.

```
$('#jqm-home').live("pagecreate", function () {
    $(".navmain2").each(function () {
        if ($(this).children("ul").length == 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```